# How to obtain a diffeomorphism between $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ and $ (\mathbb{C}\!\smallsetminus\!\{0\})\times\mathbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups

Could someone please give me a tip on how to show that the map

> $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R}) \to (\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\})\times\mathbb{R}$

\begin{equation}\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}\to(a+i c,ab+cd)\end{equation} 
is a diffeomorphism? Thanks.

Comment: What is the actual function you're referring to? Given an element $\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$ of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$, to which element of the codomain do you send it?

Comment: @user126467, you *should* write down specifically what function you mean in your question's body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint.** The relation
$$
ad-cb=1,
$$
requires that $(a,c)\ne (0,0)$, and says that the point $(d,b)$ lies on the line 
$$ax-cy=1,$$ which is described parametrically by 
$$
(x,y)=t(c,a)+(a^2+c^2)^{-1/2}(a,-c).
$$
Thus
$$
\left(\begin{matrix}a &b \\ c& d\end{matrix}\right) 
=\left(\begin{matrix}a &at-c(a^2+c^2)^{-1/2} \\ 
c& ct+a(a^2+c^2)^{-1/2}\end{matrix}\right) 
\to (a+ic)\times \{t\},
$$
is the diffeomorphism.

**Note.** This diffeomorphism allows us obtain also a full description of the fundamental group of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb R)$:
$$
\pi_1\!\big(\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb R)\!\big)=\mathbb Z.
$$